# Прерывание многопоточности

Tags: c#

пишу программу, работающую с несколькими модемами. Для ускорения работы использую async await методы и запускаю их асинхронно.
Открытие порта проходит нормально. Далее инициализирую модем

```
    int ModemConnect(string modemNum)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        _port.Write("+++\r\n");
        _port.Write("ATE1\r\n");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        _port.Write("ATH0\r\n"); // установка режима ожидания 
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        _port.Write("AT+IFC=0,2\r\n"); // устанавливается режим контроля над передачей
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        _port.Write("at+cbst=7,0,1\r\n"); // устанавливается прозрачный режим 
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(modemNum, @"(8|\+)9[0-9]{9}"))
            return 11;
        _port.Write("ATDT " + modemNum + "\r\n" + " ");
        return 0;
    }
```

Дело доходит до набора номера, соответствующая AT команда на модем уходит. Дальше приложение вываливается с ошибкой

"Дескриптор SafeHandle был закрыт".

Тут я не знаю, в чем дело.. Может быть из-за того, что установление связи с модемом - длительная операция (до 1 минуты). Но как в этом убедиться и что делать дальше?

Comment: Ещё под .net 2.0 GC уничтожал наш модуль связи по GPRS из памяти, пришлось раз в двадцать минут посылать им dummy сообщения, может и у Вас что то такое? Простите, что поместил в ответ, но иначе не могу комментировать и следить за темой. Заинтересован, как удастся справиться с этой проблемой.

Comment: Не вижу у вас упомянутых вами async и await.

Comment: Что у вас за модем? Модель? Ссылку на документацию по командам модема можете дать?

Answer (score -1):

```
private async Task<int> ModemConnect(string modemNum)
    {
        //проверку входных параметров
        //нужно делать в самомом начале метода
        //а не в середине работы,
        //когда вы начали дергать модем
        //и вставать в ожидание
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(modemNum, @"(8|\+)9[0-9]{9}"))
            return 11;

        //Thread.Sleep() - блокирует поток,
        //CPU совсем "не обращает на него внимание".
        //Thread.Sleep(1000);

        //Если вы хотите "подождать" в методе, который
        //выполняет input/output то надо использовать Task.Delay()
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        _port.Write("+++\r\n");
        _port.Write("ATE1\r\n");

        await Task.Delay(500);
        _port.Write("ATH0\r\n"); // установка режима ожидания

        await Task.Delay(500);
        _port.Write("AT+IFC=0,2\r\n"); // устанавливается режим контроля над передачей

        await Task.Delay(500);
        _port.Write("at+cbst=7,0,1\r\n"); // устанавливается прозрачный режим

        await Task.Delay(500);
        _port.Write("ATDT " + modemNum + "\r\n" + " ");

        //возвращать int в качестве
        //ответа на невычисляемые задачи,
        //а с целью отражения успеха/неуспеха/ошибки
        //фиговая практика (вы не на С пишите в конце концов).
        //для этого нужно использовать enum или спец.класс,
        //на худой конец константное строковое значение
        return 0;
    }
```

Вызывать такой метод надо так

```
int result = await ModemConnect("1234567");
```